# JSON error on device for contacts api from PhoneGap / Cordova but works on Ripple

Tags: cordova

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        alert('Add Listener');
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('Device is ready');
            navigator.contacts.find("*", function(contacts) {
                for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                    $('body').append('<div>' + contacts[i].displayName + '</div>');
                }
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Contacts.find failed: ' + error);
            });
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

My PhoneGap is setup to version 2.2.0. The code is in a zip file with just:

index.html
app/lib/jquery.min.js

No cordova-2.2.0.js, no config.xml.

When I test in Ripple, it gives me a list of contacts as expected.

When I deploy the app on my phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus, running Jelly Bean), it gives me an alert windows saying "Contacts.find failed: JSON error".

It looks like the method "navigator.contacts.find" failed.

At first I thought this is a permissions issue, but when I install the app, I was able to see the app asking for "Your personal information" which contains reading contacts from the phone.

I am wondering what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. There are two issues.

First issue is:

```
navigator.contacts.find("*", function(contacts) { ...
```

it should be:

```
navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function(contacts) { ...
```

The second problem is using cordova 2.2.0. For some reason, using cordova 2.1.0 works. Perhaps this is in the setup from within PhoneGap build.

Comment: i am confirming that this is a problem with 2.2.0.  I downgraded to 2.1.0 and everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, too. I found out a solution to resolve it.

Please add 'option' parameter to navigator.contacts.find method.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find

After I add the parameter, it works.

Answer (score 0):

IF you dident create the config.xml file it wont work when u installed it on your real phone :)

If you want to work with the phone specifics functionalites from phonegap you need to grant access to them.

Createa a config.xml file and add the following line:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>



Here is an example of the config file. Also read:
```

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode="10" 
    version   = "1.0.0">


<name>PhoneGap Example</name>

<description>
    An example for phonegap build docs. 
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    Hardeep Shoker 
</author>


<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>

</widget>
```

You dont need to psysically have the cordova-2.2.0.js file on your HDD.  As long as you refer to it with a tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

Everything is fine on that front.

Comment: Try what i suggested, i hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, But that isn't the problem. Now I am seeing that it requires only contact information when I install the app, but I am getting the exact same error when I run the app. I believe the configuration you do under "Settings" in PhoneGap automatically creates config.xml file for you so that's why it can be omitted.